# Inserting one png above another by coords

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gm

How I can insert one page above another in specific cords.
I want to use gm library for imageMagic but I cant find such way.
maybe another libs exist

Comment: Please show what you've tried and clarify your question a bit. Take a look at [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple, just use the -geometry option.

```
gm composite -geometry +x+y overlay.png background.png output.png
```

x and y are your coordinates where you'd like to have your overlay image start at